# Make Pry's return shorter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

in Rails/Pry, I would like to limit my return value to N (shorter) number of lines. Either by just cutting off long stacktrace errors in rails, or like, anything over 10 lines gets unix-less-esque view with the colon on the bottom of the terminal. Thank you for your time!

It is something like this in IRB i believe
context.back_trace_limit=5